# Remodel data and transforamtion in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

1)I fetch data from third party Oracle database and load into my temporary tables in my database
2) do the transformation using SSIS ETL - have some static tables too which are referred
3) SSIS loads the data into final database used for adhoc business queries.

Now to remodel this in cassandra

1) third party database remain as is
2) can i directly load into temporary tables in cassandra, but then how can i do the transformation and do joins with static tables

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra data model is very specific. If you do wrong modeling, you're screwed. So before dumping every into Cassandra, you should first analyze your requirements to determine the read & write path.

About joins forget it, nothing such as join exists in Cassandra. The key is de-normalization

Comment: Thanks doanduyhai, but does de-normalization can act as as substitute for transformation, say for eg abc field of output table is calculated using a multiplication of xyz field of a static table and jkl field of third party table, at some point i have to join third party table with static table to get the output field, will that be done through ETL or you are suggesting cassandra remodelling can achieve it.

Comment: Cassandra data modeling is only for **storage** and **query**. All joins operations where you need some logic should be done in client code. As an example, you store a static table called *referential_data*, a *third_party* table and your *output_table*. Then with Cassandra, you read from *referential_data* and *third_party* tables, do the joins in the client code then insert results into your *output_table*

Comment: Got it, something like talend ( ETL) have to be used to do the transformation or as suggested by you in client code. Appreciate your inputs thx.